# Ошибка FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: картинка]

Командная строка выдает ошибку `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, подробнее на скрине (столкнулся с такой проблемой, изучая учебник Лутца по Python и не могу сдвинуться в изучении языка из-за этого)

Буду признателен за помощь.

Код script1.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.platform)
print(2**100)
x='spam!'
print(x*8)
```

Comment: Ну в общем да, пробел - фиговая замена слэшу.

Comment: @Akina я где-то допустил ошибку?

Comment: На скриншоте я вижу в сообщении об ошибке следующее имя файла: `'c:\\python370 script1.py'`. Тогда как согласно окну эксплорера оно должно быть `'c:\\python370\script1.py'`.

Comment: @Akina и как мне это исправить,я же не прописывал эту команду?

Comment: А кто? я вообще к тому компьютеру не прикасался... само собой оно не запустится, кто-то должен дать команду - вот к этому кому-то и адресуйте вопросы. На скриншоте даже самой команды не видно...

Comment: @Akina команда exec(open(‘script1.py).read()) разве нет? я вводил python в строке,а потом саму команду. как исправить проблему? я просто туплю над этим уже который час. это мой первый язык,много чего не знаю

Comment: @Akina,в самой последней команде ошибка,то,что выше,это я не правильно ввел команду

Comment: @Akina вот содержимое скрипта      import sys
  print(sys.platform)
   print(2**100)
  x='spam!'
  print(x*8)

Comment: @ДанилАрефьев код добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @insolor,какой конкретно код следует добавить?

Comment: @ДанилАрефьев, тот который вы пишете в комментариях. Комментарии не имеют возможности форматировать многострочный код, они просто для этого не предназначены. Все дополнения к вопросу нужно вносить в сам вопрос.

Comment: @insolor могу ли я как-то с вами связаться,соц сети,или как-то еще,если вы не против помочь?

Comment: @ДанилАрефьев, в этом нет необходимости. У вас не настолько сложная проблема, что ее нельзя решить прямо здесь.

Comment: @ДанилАрефьев, у меня не получается воспроизвести вашу ошибку. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT4ga.png . Если вы запускаете python.exe напрямую из этой же папки, то такой проблемы не должно возникать. Выполните еще в python команды `import os` `os.getcwd()`. Должно вывестись `'C:\\python370'` (если все правильно).

Comment: @insolor ввел команды,вот что вышло на экран 'C:\\Users\\Acer'

Comment: @АрефьевДанил как Python запускаете?

Comment: @insolor через командную строку,через команду python

Comment: @АрефьевДанил, как именно? Из какой папки запускаете?

Comment: @insolor, я запускаю не полным путем к файлу,просто пишу команду python в командной строке и все

Answer (score 6):

Есть различные способы задать путь к файлу или папке:

- `c:\python370\script1.py` - абсолютный путь
- `script1.py` - относительный путь, задается относительно текущей рабочей директории. В данном случае файл должен находиться в текущей директории.

В вашем случае текущая директория `C:\Users\Acer`, вы пытаетесь открыть файл `script1.py`, но он у вас находится не в этой директории, а в `c:\python370`. Поэтому просто по имени файла вы файл не откроете, нужно указать полный (абсолютный) путь:

```
exec(open('c:\\python370\\script1.py').read())
```

Или запускать Python сразу из нужной директории - двойным кликом по файлу python.exe в папке `c:\python370` или в окне cmd сначала перейти в директорию, где лежит нужный файл, потом запустить python, и пробовать открыть файл.

В окне cmd:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\Михаил>
```

`C:\Users\Михаил` - это текущая директория.

Меняем текущую директорию такой командой (опять же в cmd, до запуска python):

```
cd c:\Python370
```

В python текущую директорию можно узнать, выполнив команды:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

`cwd` - сокращение от `current working directory` - текущая рабочая директория.

Поменять текущую директорию из Python можно так:

```
import os
os.chdir('c:\\python370')
```

**В итоге**, если текущая рабочая директория не совпадает с директорией, где лежит файл, то вы не сможете открыть файл просто по его имени. Нужно или указать полный (абсолютный) путь, или изменить текущую директорию.

Кстати, чтобы не экранировать обратные слеши в строке пути, можно использовать "сырые" (raw) строки, с буквой `r` перед кавычками, например:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'c:\python370')
```

Comment: огромное спасибо,очень помогли

Comment: а как сделать так,чтобы директория питона оставалась всегда,чтобы при повторном запуске командной строки была она,а не  C:\Users\Acer ?

Comment: Сделайте ярлык для cmd, в свойствах ярлыка укажите нужную рабочую папку.